# Counting the first "X" number of vowels in a text file? - while loop issue

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop

I can't seem to get this while loop to work properly.

I would like to create a function count_vowels that takes 2 arguments, a text file (filename), and a number (x). The function should open the specified text file and use a while loop to find the first x number of vowels in that text file, returning it in the form of a new string.

For instance, a text file containing aeiou with a given x parameter of 2, would output a string of "ae" instead of "aeiou". Of course it's everyday use would be more like e.g a text file containing "hello, I am a text file" with an x parameter of 5 would return "eoIaa" - The first 5 vowels.

My attempt:

```
        def count_vowels(filename,x):

        text=open(filename).read()
        vowels=("A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u")
        count = 0
        new_str=""
        while count<x:
            for char in text:
                 if char in vowels:
                     count+=1
                     new_str=new_str+char
            print new_str
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a string output of *every* vowel in the text file.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question? It is unclear how the expected behaviour differs from the desribed behaviour; please try to provide an example.

Comment: Oh sorry, i'll give it another shot

Comment: Okay, what is the programming language from your question in the first place? Is that Visual Basic? Perhaps the desired result can be achieved by moving the last `print` statement` from the loop body to after the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your loop `for char in text` runs to completion *before* the outer `while` loop gets to check `count`.

The solution is to remove the outer loop, and exit the `for` when count is enough:

```
    for char in text:
         if char in vowels:
             count += 1
             new_str += char
             if count >= x: break
    print new_str
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, so is this not possible with a while loop? I was under the impression that by saying "while count<x:" it's interpreted as "while count is less than x, if the letter is a vowel, add it to the string, add 1 to count, keep looking until count=x and stop."

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get rid of the for statement.  Here's what you're telling the program to do:

While count < X - keep looping if the count is less than X (Loop 1)

for each letter in text - Look at each letter in the text file and save the vowel (Loop 2)

Loop 2 has no ending condition so it continues on until it reaches the end of the file and loop 1 isn't re-evaluated until loop 2 has gone through all of the text.

**Update:**

----Example of how to do it with just the while statement:

Example:

```
position = 0
count = 0

while count < x:
    if text[position] in vowel:
        new_char += text[position]
        count+= 1

    position += 1
```

(The while loop will then iterate over each character in the text file without using a for loop)

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what you're saying. So how do I use "char" in just an if statement? It doesn't seem to let me